# How to copy and Paste a formula driven cell to another cell as values in Excel

Tags: excel, formula

I have an excel sheet where **"Sheet1.A3=Sheet2.A1"**

Here i want to copy the Sheet1.A3 to Sheet3.A1 as a Paste Special Value.

Do anyone knows excel formula (not VBA code) to perform the action?

Comment: It won't be a formula.  Copy `Sheet1!A3` using _Ctrl+C_, right click in `Sheet3!A1` and under the `Paste Options` select _Values_.

Comment: Are you looking for putting `=Sheet1!A3` formula in Sheet3!A1 cell?

Comment: @p_phidot, Say for example, I am having a value in Sheet1.A3 (12345) which is equal to Sheet2.A1. So in this, Sheet1.A3 is a formula cell, i want this cell to copy and paste the 12345 to Sheet3.A1 as values.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook, Actually i am not going to do any manual intervention on this. Just wanted to copy the value and paste it in the sheet as values. I am looking for any formula kinda stuffs. But its okay if there is no formulas available on this

Comment: Sounds like you need exactly what @p._phidot_ said then.  In `Sheet3!A1` type in the formula: `=Sheet1!A3`.

Comment: Thanks @DarrenBartrup-Cook . ( :

Answer (score 1):

Based on your " i want this cell to copy and paste the 12345 to Sheet3.A1 as values" statement.. I just would like to clarify.. If you target the (12345) value to be 'filled' in Sheet3.A1 , then you should put the formula in Sheet3.A1 . You cannot put a formula in Sheet1.A3 that 'make' Sheet3.A1 cell value change.

Just put the `=Sheet1!A3` formula in Sheet3!A1 will do what you need.

Hope it helps.